# Is it possible to modify the modern view of Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience

The default view of Name displaying is some small, it can not show all the filename on the screen.

Is there a way to expend the length of the displaying area?
Thank You.

Remarks:

I am using sharepoint online and it is a modern view of Document Library.

[image]

Comment: you can expand the width of each column by dragging the cell sizer at the 
 right side of column header.( like in excel)

Comment: Can it be expanded by default? So that our user doesn't have to drag every time.